# Bilinear forms and scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra

Forgive me for these may not be the correct English mathematical terms.

Let $(V, \langle, \rangle)$ be a euclidean vector space of finite dimension $n$ and $f:V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a bilinear form.
Prove there exists a unique endomorphism $f' : V \rightarrow V$ given by $\langle x, f'(y)\rangle := f(x, y)$, $\forall x, y \in V$.

Comment: Do you know that a given linear (not bilinear) map $\lambda:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ admits a representation using the scalar product (i.e. there is $y$ such that $\lambda(x) =\langle y,x\rangle \forall x$)?

Comment: No :( ... how do I prove this?

Comment: I did assume you might know this, cause it might help. If not (and if it is homework) you should have been taught some other theorem which allows you to deduce the claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Let $B$ be an orthonormal base of $V$. Then its associated Gram matrix is $I_n$, where $n = dim(V)$.

$$
\langle x, y \rangle = X^TY \implies \forall g \in End(V), \langle x, g(y) \rangle = X^TM_{B}(g)Y
$$

where $M_{B}(g)Y$ is the matrix associated to $g$ in base $B$, and $End(V)$ is the vector space of endomorfisms in $V$.

Now, $f(x, y) = X^TM_{B}(f)Y$, where $M_{B}(f)$ is the matrix associated to the bilinear form $f$ in base $B$. Therefore:

$$
\exists! f' : V \rightarrow V : \langle x, f'(y)\rangle = f(x, y) \iff \exists! f' : V \rightarrow V : X^TM_{B}(f')Y = X^TM_{B}(f)Y
$$

This has to happen $\forall X, Y \in V$, hence $M_{B}(f') = M_{B}(f)$.

And $f'$ is unique because it is fully described by the images of the vectors in $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B = (b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ be an orthogonal basis of $V$. Then

1. A bilinear form $f \,:\, V\times V \to \mathbb{R}$ is fully described by the scalars $a_{ij} = f(b_i,b_j)$, $1 \leq i,j \leq n$.
2. An endomorphism $f' \,:\, V \to V$ is fully described by the images of the $b_i$, i.e. by the vectors $f_i = f(b_i)$, $1 \leq i \leq n$.
3. For every $x \in V$, either $\langle x,y \rangle = 0$ for *all* $y \in V$, or there is an $y_c \in V$ for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$ with  $\langle x,y_c \rangle = c$.

Use (3) to find the $f_i$ mentioned by $i$, and (1)+(2) to show that $f'$ is unique.

Comment: Thank you, using an orthogonal base makes things easier. I reach the conclusion that if $f_{ij}$ denotes the entry of the matrix associated to $f'$ in $B$ then $f_{ij} = \frac{a_{ij}}{b_i}$.